# Sending mail using gmail from behind a proxy using java

Tags: java, email, proxy, smtp, gmail

My current code is (I am using correct username and password in actual code) :-

```
            public class MailTry {

                public static void main(String[] args) {

                    final String username = "user@gmail.com";
                    final String password = "pass";

                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

                    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                        }
                      });

                    try {

                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
                        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

                        Transport.send(message);

                        System.out.println("Done");

                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am getting following exceptions in above code:-

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
              nested exception is:
                java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
                at MailTry.main(MailTry.java:63)
            Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
              nested exception is:
                java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
                at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
                ....
                ....
```

For http client I use proxy using following java code and it works perfectly:

```
             String proxyHost = "172.22.6.26";
             int proxyPort = 80;
             Properties systemSettings = System.getProperties();
             systemSettings.put("http.proxyPort",proxyPort);
             systemSettings.put("http.proxyHost",proxyHost);
```

I am not sure what is the exact problem but I think it should be related to proxy or firewall. I have tried several codes to use proxy in smtp client but none of them are working properly.

Comment: A _web_ proxy won't help you sending mail via SMTP ;)

Comment: @fge I know that it won't actually I have given that to tell the ip and port of my proxy... any idea what might be the problem ?

Comment: A proxy will not improve performance. Just connect directly to the Gmail SMTP server.